# in Iphone ReachableViaWiFi is always true even though when WIFI is off

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, wifi

I am trying to find WIFI connection status in iphone, but it is always showing WIFI as true even though when WIFI is off. I am checking this using ReachableViaWiFi. I am not getting what is the problem?. Doing in Xcode 4.6.3

```
  Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
  NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

  if(internetStatus==ReachableViaWiFi){  /Always only this condition is executing
  NSLog(@"Reachable VIA WIFI");
  }
  if(internetStatus==ReachableViaWWAN) {
  NSLog(@"Reachable VIA WLAN");
  }
  if(internetStatus==NotReachable){
  NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write after

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
```

the next code

```
[reachability startNotifier];
```

By the way, you should to upgrade to xCode 5 if you want to upload your app to App Store or it will be rejected

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on an actual device or on the simulator?  I compiled the Apple Reachability example and on the simulator TCP/IP Routing available always indicates "Reachable WiFi" regardless of the WiFi connection status.  On an IPAD with both WiFi and 4G connection the code operates correctly returning either WiFi, WWAN or none.

Comment: Ya i am testing it in simulator, but why it is not taking ReachableViaWWAN as true?

Comment: I don't know, but that is why you really need to test on a real device - the simulator only goes so far

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that SystemConfiguration framework is added to your build settings..
I have similar problem after adding the framework it works fine as expected ...
Thanks...